# If $\phi$ is Cantor function, is $f(x)= \sup \{t \in [0,1] : \phi(t) \leq x\}$ strictly increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, cantor-set

Let $\phi:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be the [Cantor-Lebesgue function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).

Define $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ by $f(x)= \sup \{t \in [0,1] : \phi(t) \leq x\}$.

I am interested in analyzing properties of the function $f$. (For example, is it continuous? Measurable? What is its range? Is it strictly monotone?) To avoid asking an overly broad question, however, I will restrict the scope of this SE question to the following:

> Is $f$ strictly increasing on $[0,1]$?

I see already that $f$ is an increasing function (in the not necessarily strict sense). Why? Given $0\leq a<b\leq 1$, we have $\{t \in [0,1]: \phi(t) \leq a\} \subseteq \{t \in [0,1]: \phi(t) \leq b\}$ obviously, implying that $sup\{t \in [0,1]: \phi(t) \leq a\} \leq sup\{t \in [0,1]: \phi(t) \leq b\}$. So $f(a) \leq f(b)$.

But I do not see how to show that $f(a) \neq f(b)$. My intuition says that it is probably true and has something to do with finding some $\phi(t)$ sandwiched between $a$ and $b$, but I don't see the rigorous argument.

Comment: Have you tried some specific values of $f$? Like, do you know what is $f(\frac12)$, is it $\frac13$ or $\frac23$? Perhaps that would help you answer your questions. (The answer is yes, for any non-decreasing function $\phi$, has something to do with the vertical line test.)

Comment: @Mirko Thank you. Your insight that the result is true for any non-decreasing function $\phi$ (not just Cantor, not just continuous) was very helpful and I have shown my desired result.

Comment: Apparently I was mistaken that continuity is not needed. I posted a detailed answer.

Comment: @Mirko Actually, now that you mentioned it, I looked again at my proof that $f$ is strictly increasing and I used Intermediate Value Theorem on $\phi$.

Comment: I used the IVT too (and IVT together with monotone implies continuous, so one has to assume continuous). In the answer I posted I don't seem to mention the IVT, but I used IVT before I came up with the version that I posted (that shows $\phi(f(x))=x$ for all $x$). I didn't think of all details and the complete picture before I posted my first comment, it seems I implicitly assumed that the function was continuous and IVT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result that $f$ is strictly increasing holds for any non-decreasing and continuous function $\phi$ satisfying $\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi(1)=1$, not just for the Cantor-Lebesgue function.

Here is an example that if $\phi$ is not continuous, then $f$ need not be strictly increasing. Let $\phi(t)=0$ for $t<\frac12\,,$ let $\phi(t)=t$ for $t>\frac12$ 
(and let $\phi(\frac12)$ be any value between $0$ and $\frac12$ inclusive). Then $f(0)=\frac12=f(\frac12)$, and $f$ is constant $f\equiv\frac12$ on the interval $[0,\frac12]$, so $f$ is not strictly increasing.

Now assume that $\phi$ is any non-decreasing and continuous function on $[0,1]$ 
with $\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi(1)=1$. 
We will show that $\phi(f(x))=x$ for every $x\in[0,1]$. 
We have $\phi(f(x))\le x$ by continuity of $\phi$. 
Indeed, if $\phi(f(x))>x$ then there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that 
$\phi(f(x)-\varepsilon)>x$. 
(Note that $f(x)>0$ since $\phi(f(x))>x\ge0=\phi(0)$.)
If we let $s=f(x)-\varepsilon$ then 
$\phi(s)>x$, hence $f(x)\le s$ by the definition of $f(x)$, 
obtaining a contradiction $f(x)\le f(x)-\varepsilon$.
Next we show that $\phi(f(x))\ge x$. If $\phi(f(x))<x$ then 
by continuity of $\phi$ there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that 
$\phi(f(x)+t)<x$ for all $t\in[f(x),f(x)+\varepsilon)$, 
resulting in the contradiction $f(x)\ge f(x)+\varepsilon$ 
(again using the definition of $f(x)$). 
(Note that $f(x)<1$ since $\phi(f(x))<x\le1=\phi(1)$.)

It follows that if $0\le a<b\le1$ then $0\le f(a)<f(b)\le1$. 
Indeed $\phi(f(a))=a<b=\phi(f(b))$, hence $f(a)\neq f(b)$, and it was already proved by the OP that $f(a)\le f(b)$.

The rest of this answer deals specifically with the 
Cantor-Lebesgue function and treats the remaining questions.

$f$ is not continuous because of the horisontal line segments on the graph of $\phi$. For example, if $x<\frac12$ then $f(x)<\frac13$, and it is easily seen that 
$\lim\limits_{x\to\frac12^-}f(x)=\frac13\neq f(\frac12)=\frac23$. On the other hand, $f$ is continuous from the right (using that in the definition of $f(x)$ we work with the inequality $\phi(t)\le x$ rather than $\phi(t)<x$).

The range of $f$ is a subset of the Cantor (middle-third) set $C$. Indeed, if $(p,q)$ is any of the "middle-third" intervals removed in the construction of $C$, then the range of $f$ misses $[p,q)$. We have that $p<q$ and $(p,q)\times\{c\}$ is a subset of the graph $G$ of $\phi$ (and $p$ and $q$ are some fractions with denominators $3^n$, and $c$ is a fraction with denominator $2^n$). Then $\lim\limits_{x\to c^-}f(x)=p\neq q=f(c)=\lim\limits_{x\to c^+}f(x)$.

It follows that $f$ is not measurable. Indeed take any set $M\subset[0,1]$ that is not measurable. Then $f(M)\subset C$ hence it has measure $0$ (as a subset of the measure $0$ Cantor set $C$), in particular it is measurable. The function $f$ is $1-1$ (being strictly increasing), hence $M=f^{-1}(f(M))$ showing that $f$ is not measurable.

One could also easily sketch the graph of $f$, at least as easy as one could sketch the graph $G$ of the Cantor-Lebesgue function $\phi$. The function $f$ is "almost" an inverse function of $\phi$. We obtain the graph of $f$ by the following steps. (a) reflect the graph $G$ of $\phi$ about the diagonal $y=x$, (b) remove all but the very top point of each of the vertical intervals that we obtain this way (vertical intervals that result from the reflection about $y=x$ of the horizontal intervals on the graph $G$ of $\phi$).

Here is a picture (from Wikipedia) of the graph of the 
Cantor-Lebesgue function $\phi$.

[image: graph of the Cantor-Lebesgue function]

Following is a picture of the graph of the 
Cantor-Lebesgue function reflected about the line $y=x$.

[image: graph of the Cantor-Lebesgue function reflected about the diagonal]

Finally, a picture of the graph of $f$.

[image: picture of the graph of f]

Comment: +1 Once we've established that $rng(f) \subseteq C$, it's obvious that $f$ can't be continuous because otherwise Intermediate Value Theorem would be violated.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a little more on what $rng(f)$ actually is? It occurred to me before that $rng(f) \subseteq C$, and from this I made an educated guess that $rng(f)=C$. I'm surprised that it's not!

Comment: points like $\frac13$ are in $C$ but not in $rng(f)$. We obtain $rng(f)$ the same way we obtain $C$, except that instead of removing open middle-third intervals $(p,q)$, we remove left-closed right-open middle-third intervals $[p,q)$ (thus leaving $q$ in  $rng(f)$ but removing $p$). So, $\frac13,\frac19,\frac79$ are in $C$ but not in $rng(f)$, while $\frac23,\frac29,\frac89$ are both in $C$ and in $rng(f)$. As another variation of a proof that $f$ is not continuous, once we know $rng(f)\subset C$, if $f$ were continuous it would have been measurable, but it is not :)

Comment: In other words, $rng(f)= \bigcap _i A_i$ where $A_1=[0,1/3) \cup [2/3,1]$ and $A_2=[0,1/9) \cup [2/9, 1/3) \cup [2/3, 7/9) \cup [8/9,1]$ and so on. Is this right?

Comment: Right. There is an alternative description in terms of the sum of certain ceries, need to think of the details though.

Comment: Thank you. Also, is there a natural way to write the range in terms of $C_i$, where $C_1=[0,1/3] \cup [2/3,1]$ and $C_2=[0,1/9] \cup [2/9,1/3] \cup [2/3,7/9] \cup [8/9,1]$ and so on?

Comment: I do not see ... you get $C=\cap_i C_i$ in a natural way, and you need to mention then that you remove $1/3,1/9,7/9$ etc. Alternatively, $C=\{\sum_n\frac{a_n}{3^n}:a_n\in\{0,2\}\}$ and $rng(f)$ is the set of only those  sums where $a_n=0$ for infinitely many $n$ (and, union with singleton $\{1\}$). (And, in my preceding comment "certain ceries" should of course be  "certain series".) Here is one more description: to get $rng(f)$ from $C$ you remove all $\frac j{3^n}$ where $j$ is odd and $j<3^n$ (but I don't find this latter description very elegant, as it lists some point not in $C$ anyway.)

Comment: You have two types of points in $\cap_i A_i$, one like $\frac23$, a right endpoint of one of the removed intervals, and others like $\frac14$, not an endpoint of any of the removed intervals. For  $\frac23$, from some point on you always pick "left middle-thirds". For $\frac14$ you pick left as well as right middle-thirds infinitely often. If $p$ is of either type,verify that $\phi(p)<\phi(q)$ whenever $p<q$. Note $\frac23=\sum_n\frac{a_n}{3^n}$, $a_1=2,a_2=a_3=...=0$ (pick left middle-thirds for $n\ge2$), and $\frac14=\sum_n\frac{a_n}{3^n}$ with $a_{odd}=0, a_{even}=2$ (alternate left,right).

Comment: Would it be true that $f(x)=x$ for any $x \in \bigcap _i A_i$? Or is that only true if $x$ is of the first type (i.e. left endpoint)?

Comment: Never mind my previous comment. We can't have $f(x)=x$ for all $x \in \bigcap _i A_i$ since $f(1/2)=2/3$ and $f$ is strictly increasing, implying $f(2/3)>2/3$.

Comment: If $x=\sum_n\frac{a_n}{3^n}$ then $\phi(x)=\sum_n\frac{a_n/2}{2^n}$. For example $x=1/3$, $a_1=0,a_{n\ge2}=2$, $\phi(1/3)=\sum_{n\ge2}\frac{2/2}{2^n}=\frac12$. For $x=2/3$, $a_1=2,a_{n\ge2}=0$, $\phi(2/3)=\frac{2/2}2=\frac12$. For $f(2/3)$ first find $a_n$ so $\phi(x=\sum_n\frac{a_n}{3^n})=\frac23=$ $1/2+1/8+1/32+...=\sum_n\frac{a_n/2}{2^n}$, so $a_{odd}=2,a_{even}=0$.  Thus $x=2/3+2/27+2/243+...=\frac34$, $\phi(\frac34)=\frac23$, and $\frac34$ is not an endpoint of a removed middle-third interval, so $\phi^{-1}(\frac23)=\frac34$ is well-defined and  $f(\frac23)=\phi^{-1}(\frac23)=\frac34$.